# CSS3 Select all td in top level table with nested tables

Tags: html, css

I started out with CSS3 and HTML5 today, with Codecademy.

HTML:

```
<table class="main">
    <tr class="questioncontainer">
        <td class="serialnumber">1.</td>
        <td class="question" colspan="2">What is the question?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <table class="notmain">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="answer">Answer 1</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="answer">Answer 2</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="answer">Answer 3</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="answer">Answer 4</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.main {
    text-align: center;
    width: 75vw;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #fff3f3;
}

table.main tr td:first-child {
    border-right: thin solid lightgray;
}
```

I wish to select all the left most table cells of the top most table. That'd be the first `td` of each `tr` in the topmost table.

`table.main tr td:first-child` selects the `td`'s of the inner table too, which I don't want. I tried using `table.main>tr>td:first-child`, `.main>tr>td:first-child` and `table>tr>td:first-child`, none of them worked, didn't even select the top table's `td`'s.

What would be the correct selector here, and what was wrong with the ones I tried? I am trying to avoid setting a class for those `td`'s.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x70srmae/1/

Comment: Try `table.main .container td:first-child`

Comment: @TylerH There isn't a `container` class in my code.

Comment: I'm looking at one right now. Your first `tr` has that class. EDIT - it looks like your Fiddle code is different from your posted code. Please use the same code for your Fiddle and your post :-)

Comment: @TylerH Sorry, residue. Updated. Anyways, didn't work, even brought back `container`.

Comment: see kmoe's answer. It's the same as my comment except with your updated class name. You also don't need `table.main`; `.main` works just fine.

Comment: I must have caught this question just before it was updated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried using `table.main>tr>td:first-child`, `.main>tr>td:first-child` and `table>tr>td:first-child`, none of them worked, didn't even select the top table's `td`'s.

That’s because the `tr` are *not* children of the table, but only of `tbody` (that browsers insert when building the DOM from your HTML).

Something like

```
table.main > tbody > tr > td:first-child { background:red; }
```

or anything similar that takes the implicitly generated `tbody` into account, will work – see http://jsfiddle.net/x70srmae/2/

(Still referencing the `.main` class here, because otherwise that selector will match the first `td` inside `tr` in the `tbody` of the *inner* `table` as well.)

Comment: This worked, thanks. Direct descendant selectors have to follow the full DOM path, though? Didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there! You can use the `.questioncontainer` class to specify which `tr` you want:

`table.main .questioncontainer td:first-child`

http://jsfiddle.net/kmoe/c8wpsxzs/2/

Comment: `table` before `.main` is unnecessary, by the way.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but I want *all* the `td`'s, not just the ones in `questioncontainer`.

Comment: So you want all the 'td's in the `.main` table except those in the `.notmain` table?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I want.

Comment: Have you tried `.main td:first-child { border-right: thin solid lightgray; } .notmain td:first-child { border-right: none; }` ?